# Is there any way to re use form data from previous page?

Tags: php, forms, get

I am sending data from page1.php to page2.php with the GET method. So in the URL, I am getting the values as:

```
http://mydomain.com/page2.php?value1=myname&value2=xyz123
```

Now, here, in page2.php I am adding another form that I want to send to page2.php (self) on submit with the format as follows:

```
http://mydomain.com/page2.php?value1=myname&value2=xyz123&value3=1234
```

What I want to do is to add the new value at the end of the previous values in the URL.

Is there any way I can reuse the data that I got from the previous page? I have tried the following code

```
<form method="get" action="'."http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'">
```

But it is sending value to `http://mydomain.com/page2.php?value3=1234` rather to `http://mydomain.com/page2.php?value1=myname&value2=xyz123&value3=1234`

I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: You can **construct** the url string,  adding new values.  But keep in mind that this is not a a safe way to parse data.  It's vulnerable to hacks and attacks.  Consider using POST instead of GET,  consider using sessions instead.

Comment: Thanks @datelligent. Can you please tell me how I can construct the url string or give me a link where I can find a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `POST` method (instead of `GET`) to avoid the password in the URL.

With `GET`, the data are shown into the URL. With `POST`, the data are included into the HTTP request but are not displayed into the URL. Using `POST`, the user think **it's safer**.

---

About your question, one way is to put in your form some hidden input:

```xml
<input type="hidden" name="uname" value="<?php echo $_GET['uname']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<?php echo $_GET['pass']; ?>" />
```

But again, this is not a good idea because **the password is visible in the source code**.

An other way is to set a *session* variable like this:

```php
<?php

$_SESSION['uname'] = $_GET['uname'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $_GET['pass'];

?>
```

But again, **it is not a good idea to store passwords into session array**. If you want to avoid that, you can store a unique id per user into `$_SESSION['id']`.

In order to use sessions, you will need a call to `session_start()` before html (avoid any space).

You can find more information about sessions in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I used uname,pass as an example. In reality, I shall send some regional values like country, city etc. In the second page, I am asking for phone number, if it is available in the database, then it will redirect to the login page, or to the registration page. But I am unable to add the new value (phone number) at the end of the url.

Comment: People do not like to see their personal data in the URL, even country, city, etc., be careful with that. But if you really want to implement that, you will need hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hidden inputs on your form. So when page1 posts to page2, the generated HTML of page2 will contain those values. Later when page2 is submitted, it will send out the values on these hidden fields + the entered value for phone. Something like the following:

```
  <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="uname" value="<?= $uname ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<?= $pass ?>" />

    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" />
  </form>
```

Remember to escape HTML before putting it on the 's value attribute.

Comment: In the page, the number of values are dynamic. Also, there are at least 15+ attributes in the url for each submission. So, it is very tough to create a hidden field. Is there any way I can embed the new value to the url?